# azure apim import policy - Too many characters in character literal

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I'm trying to import a policy to azure api management using a bicep template as follows:

```
resource allOpsPolicy 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis/policies@2021-12-01-preview' = {
  name: 'policy'
  parent: apimapi_v1
  properties: {
    value: loadTextContent('all-ops-policy.xml')
    format: 'xml'
  }
}
```

The content of the all-ops-policy.xml file is as follows:

```xml
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <choose>
            <when condition="@(context.Request.OriginalUrl.ToString().EndsWith("Public") == false)">
                <rewrite-uri template="@(String.Concat(context.Request.OriginalUrl.ToString(),"/", "MapServer"))" copy-unmatched-params="false" />
            </when>
            <otherwise />
        </choose>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

When run I get the following error:

> One or more fields contain incorrect values: (Code: ValidationError)
>
> - 'Public' is an unexpected token. Expecting white space.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was the value of the format property of the allOpsPolicy resource.

I changed from

> format: 'xml'

to

> format: 'rawxml'

then it worked!

Thanks to Nisha for solving this one

Answer (score 2):

Please replace the single quotes ` with double quotes ".

```cs
context.Request.OriginalUrl.ToString().EndsWith('Public') == false)
```

```cs
context.Request.OriginalUrl.ToString().EndsWith("Public") == false
```

It seems there's also one single quote too much:

```cs
String.Concat(context.Request.OriginalUrl.ToString(),'/'', 'MapServer')
```

```cs
String.Concat(context.Request.OriginalUrl.ToString(),"/", "MapServer")
```

Complete policy:

```xml
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <choose>
            <when condition="@(context.Request.OriginalUrl.ToString().EndsWith("Public") == false)">
                <rewrite-uri template="@(String.Concat(context.Request.OriginalUrl.ToString(),"/", "MapServer"))" copy-unmatched-params="false" />
            </when>
            <otherwise />
        </choose>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

Issue is not reproducable:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer Markus. I tried again with a copy and pasted of your policy but this gave: One or more fields contain incorrect values: (Code: ValidationError)
 - 'Public' is an unexpected token. Expecting white space. I will update the question to reflect

Comment: @RobBowman It's working on my machine. I copied the entire policy from the answer and pasted it into APIM. Saving was successful. No error message,

Comment: Hi Markus, please see answer. You're right, no problem with the policy you gave - this issue was with how I was attempting to load into apim.